# Java WatchKey still valid after path deletion (Windows only)

Tags: java, directory, nio

In case of the question has already been asked before, please point out an answer.

I was reading this tutorial on [Watching a Directory for Changes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) and the [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java) where the program is supposed to exit if the directory (path) is no longer available - deleted.

That happens to be the case only if the file is deleted (completely) using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>.

In case of a "simple" delete (the one that makes the directory/file land in the recycle bin), the `WatchKey` is still valid as if the file wasn't deleted at all.

This is a frustrating behavior because users may delete files/directories using either way most probably the second way.

How to make sure the `WatchKey` becomes invalid after a "simple" deletion (by pressing <kbd>Del</kbd>)?

Tested on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

> the example program is supposed to exit if the directory(path) is no longer available - deleted

No it isn't. It is supposed to exit if it runs out of registered keys, i.e. if the directory becomes empty. What you want is a delete-watch on the directory itself.

Comment: The tutorial says: `Play with creating, deleting, and editing files *in* the *test* directory.When any of these events occurs, a message is printed to the console.When you have finished, delete the *test* directory and WatchDir exits.`And the documentation: `the key remains valid until ... 2.Cancelled implicitly, because the object is *no longer accessible*`.So it is actually supposed to exit when the directory under 'watch' is deleted.Thinking about it, why would it exit after the directory becomes empty?What if a file is added?And would the program keep running if there's nothing to work on?

Comment: @nt.bas Then the text of the tutorial is wrong. The code only exits when the directory becomes empty, as you can see for yourself. The *solution* to your problem is still to watch the directory itself.

Comment: assuming the tutorial is wrong, what do you make of the documentation. Because if it is supposed to exit when the directory becomes empty as you claim, how does that make sense as a sound design?IMO it doesn't because the directory being empty doesn't mean the programmer doesn't want to continue watching it. He might want to check for an ENTRY_CREATE event, for example. And in that regard, the API behaves as predicted! I suggest you try to run the provided code sample and check its behavior with regard of what the API promises. (to cont)

Comment: (cont) If you look at the source code and the docs, when you register a WatchKey,  it is with regards to a directory so that its content can be watched. As such I don't understand what you mean by `The code only exits when the directory becomes empty, as you can see for yourself.` The program runs fine even with an empty directory, waiting for events. And what's is of interest here is rather the validity of the WatchKey not that of the entire code. Thanks!